# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 "

Tags: java, awt-eventqueue

I am very to new to Java programming and I am taking a class based on Java. I am currently doing this coffee project which is based on boolean and RadioButtons. I believe I am almost done with it except I get this error message on the console. If there is any other mistakes please let me know so I can fix it!

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 "
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
```

---

```
    public void purchase()
    {
        //local variables
        String  quantityString, buttonString, nameString, coffeeType;

        float subTotalFloat, priceFloat, taxFloat, grandTotalFloat;
        int quantityInteger;

        //Format the values to currency format
        DecimalFormat valueDecimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("$#0.00");

        //retrieve the input from the  user
        nameString = nameTextField.getText();
        quantityString = quantityTextField.getText();
        buttonString = coffeeType ();

        //change data types
        quantityInteger = Integer.parseInt(quantityString);
        ...
    }
```

Comment: How do you convert `"1 "` to a number? Why have you posted so much irrelevant code?

Answer (score 5):

Change your `Integer.parseInt(quantityString);` to `Integer.parseInt(quantityString.trim());` and your code will work fine!

Comment: I have changed that code and the error is gone! However, theres no display when I click the Add to Order button.

Answer (score 3):

You have an additional space in the end. Trim it to remove that spcace.

```
quantityInteger = Integer.parseInt(quantityString.trim());
```

Comment: I have changed that code and the error is gone! However, theres no display when I click the Add to Order button

Answer (score 0):

try this i found an empty space in the console message "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input **string: "1 "**(after one there is a space)
so try to find if there is any empty space taken into account by mistake, so parserint is trying to parse string + empty space.